# Wordpress new post returns 500

Tags: wordpress

I am creating a new page in Wordpress, but it returns 500:
http://d4zed.com/test-page/

What could be the reason why? The .htaccess looks pretty standard:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /d4zed-new/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /d4zed-new/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I really have no idea about how Wordpress works internally (though I have quite an experience in Rails), so I am ready to answer your additional questions.

Thank you!

Comment: You could find out what is wrong from apache's (or whichever engine) log. One possible issue is 'clean urls'.

Comment: And if I don't have access to the apache log?

Comment: I've tried running the default permalink type, `i.e. http://d4zed.com/?p=1` and managed to see that the first post is Hello World (default wordpress post). However, a redirection occurs and returns a 500 error. 

The example you gave is a different permalink structure from the original so its probably a permalink type issue, hence related to .htaccess

Comment: Is the permalink option in wp-admin changed to the `/post-title/` type?

Comment: And how can I do that?

Comment: http://d4zed.com/wp-admin > settings > permalinks **BUT BE WARNED**, if the .htaccess is not written correctly or the mods not set up correctly, you might not even be able to access wp-admin after the change.

You could check out wordpress documentation on 'clean urls' first if you want to be safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internal Server Error in WordPress can be caused due to various reasons. You can try the following options in order to solve the problem.

1. Checking wrong `.htaccess` file
   Rename `.htaccess` file. If the site loads after this then you can infer that the problem is due to wrong .`htaccess` file. So you have to create a new .htaccess file.
2. Increasing Memory Limit
   Create a file named `php.ini` and paste the code `memory_limit = 64M;` in it and upload it to WordPress root folder as well as to `wp-content`, `wp-admin` folders in order to increase the Memory Limit.
3. Deactivating plugins
   The problem can be caused by an installed plugin. So, by deactivating all plugins and activating one by one you can find out which plugin is making the problem.
4. Reuploading WordPress core folders
   If the WordPress core files are creating the problem, it can be solved by reuploading `wp-admin` and `wp-includes` folders.
5. Contacting Hosting Provider
   Contact your hosting provider. If it is a server problem they can help you.